# Строка с временной зоной в UTC число на JS

Tags: javascript

Есть ли способ без костылей сделать функцию, которая при получении строки с временной зоной, будет возвращать UTC цифру? К примеру, если отправить US/Central, она выдаст -6. Причем с учетом перехода на летнее время.

Comment: Без костылей - это как? Есть [Moment Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/), которая много всего сделает

Comment: @Pashok moment - это библиотека, которая больше не поддерживается. Ее авторы рекомендуют использовать другие сторонние библиотеки либо новый встроенный Intl

Comment: @AndreiKhotko Ну, можно же скачать исходник с конкретным интересующим местом и не подключать сторонние ссылки, которые нуждаются в поддержке авторов и тормозят загрузку сайта в целом...

Answer (score 0):

```
 function getUtcOffset(timezone) {
  const now = new Date();
  const options = { timeZone: timezone, timeZoneName: 'short' };
  const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat([], options);
  const [{ value: offsetStr }] = formatter.formatToParts(now);
  
  return offsetStr;
}

// Пример использования:
const timezone = 'America/Chicago';
const utcOffset = getUtcOffset(timezone);
console.log(`Смещение UTC для ${timezone}: ${utcOffset}`);
```

Comment: Вы явно перестарались с деструктуризацией. У меня этот код выводит `02` — сегодняшнее число, а не смещение

Comment: А у меня текущий месяц. `getUtcOffset(timezone) // Смещение UTC для America/Chicago: 9`

Comment: Так вы для себя код подгоняйте ребята )))

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, насколько это будет костылем, но вот, например, реализация, которая сразу приходит в голову. Наверняка можно придумать что-то получше.

Берем строку "US/Central", разбиваем ее, на "US" и "Central", далее, c помощью карты `map` получим идентификатор часовых поясов IANA, которые понимает JS. Дальше просто находим время по Гринвичу и время из нужного часового пояса и находим разницу между ними.

```js
/**
* @param {string} timeZone
* @returns {number} odds
*/
function getUTCFromZone(timeZone, summer = true) {
  const localDate = new Date();
  
  const [locale, region] = timeZone.split('/');
  
  /**
  * @param {string} locale "US"
  * @param {string} region "Central", "Mountain" и т.д
  * @returns {string}
  */
  function _getIANA(locale, region) {
    const map = {
      'US': {
        'Central': 'America/Chicago',
        'Western': 'America/Los_Angeles',
        'Mountain': 'America/Denver',
        'Eastern': 'America/New_York',
      },
      /**
      * сюда миожно добавить европейское время или еще какое-нибудь
      */
    };
    return map[locale][region];
  }
  
  /**
  * @param {Date} текущая дата
  * @param {number} зона типа IANA, например 'America/Chicago'
  */
  function _getUTCHour(date, timeZone) {
    const intlDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-EU', { 
      timeZone, 
      hour: "numeric",
      hour12: false,
    });
    return +intlDate.format(date);
  };
  
 const [greenwich, zone] = [
    [localDate, 'Greenwich'],
    [localDate, _getIANA(locale, region)],
 ].map(([date, timeZone]) => _getUTCHour(date, timeZone));
  
  return zone - greenwich + (summer ? - 1 : 0); // получаем разницу в часах
}


console.log(
  'US/Central', getUTCFromZone('US/Central'),
);
console.log(
  'US/Eastern', getUTCFromZone('US/Eastern'),
);
```

**P.S.** Возможно, стоило бы воспользоваться `Date.getTimezoneOffset()`.